# UTM to WGS84 relation between longitude and northing

Tags: coordinate-system

Problably I'm doing something wrong or perhaps I have a misknowledge.

I tought that Latitude ~ Northing, so if I do a conversion of two position with the same latitude I will get same northing, but not.

Converting:

40.97ºN 5.7ºW --> 272811E 4538938N (30N)

40.97ºN 5.65ºW --> 277018.6E 4538809.1N (30N)

I was wrong? I'm using a wrong tool?
I know that it's no noob question, sorry.

If I do the same in lat 0 obviously I get 0 Northing so I'm lost, I don't understand the northing difference.

Can you explain it or give a link where I can understand it.

Comment: You assume wrong that latitude projects into straight line. It projects actually into a curve. See for example this image http://www.welllog.ca/BCGS/UTMZonesBC.gif

Comment: @user30184 this should be added as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @user30184 I see, it is difficult to visualize and understand, even with the images or also looking to **Transverse Mercator**, so now I believe  it but not full understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest reason for different northing values in reprojected data is that you make conversion into UTM zone that does not suit best for your data.
Best suitable area for zone 29 (EPSG:32629) is

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32629/
Area: World - N hemisphere - 12°W to 6°W - by country

For your data at 7ºE a better zone would be zone 32 (EPSG:32632)

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32632/
Area: World - N hemisphere - 6°E to 12°E - by country

Now your data is much more to the East from the valid area of zone 29 which makes quite a lot of rotation. See what happens when a rectangle 0-40°N, 6-7°E is reprojected.

[image]

Here you can see exactly what happens to the coordinates of a linestring between 6°E and 7°E at latitude 40°N when they are projected from EPSG:4326 into UTM zone 32 or zone 29.

EPSG:4326

> LINESTRING ( 6 40, 6.1 40, 6.2 40, 6.3 40, 6.4 40, 6.5 40, 6.6 40, 6.7
>   40, 6.8 40, 6.9 40, 7 40 )

UTM 32

> LINESTRING ( 243900.35202973633 4432069.056899265, 252438.30681840706
>   4431786.238576834, 260976.12972571029 4431513.027758986, 269513.825246222 4431249.422330019, 278051.39788012113 4430995.420248629, 286588.85213297734 4430751.019547893, 295126.1925155549 4430516.218335249, 303663.4235436152 4430291.014792489, 312200.5497377032 4430075.407175731, 320737.57562295353 4429869.393815413, 329274.5057288932 4429672.973116274 )

UTM 29

> LINESTRING ( 1782840.2958445756 4537064.5427544555, 1791423.6839824151
>   4538548.30207473, 1800007.6427697674 4540042.49628661, 1808592.1742910212 4541547.136970267, 1817177.2805946714 4543062.235786607, 1825762.9636930018 4544587.804477336, 1834349.2255617785 4546123.854865045, 1842936.0681399181 4547670.398853281, 1851523.4933291816 4549227.44842662, 1860111.5029938477 4550795.015650747, 1868700.0989603875 4552373.112672537 )

Comment: Sorry @user30184 , I made you wrong, in order to simplify I'd changed the coords, and replace wrongly a - with an E, I have corrected the real numbers that I'm using. Any way with your answer and with the comments I can make a good Idea about the problem.